# I'm unable to populate the Redis Enterprise vector database hosted on Azure with vectors from a local Python script

Tags: python, database, azure, redis, chatbot

I'm trying to connect a local Python script to a Redis Enterprise vector database hosted on Azure, and populate it with vectors that I will use for implementing a chatbot. I'm able to establish the connection with redis_client.ping(), but the problem arises at the line VectorStore = Redis.from_texts(texts, embeddings, redis_conn=redis_client). I've also tried Redis.from_documents and Redis.from_texts_return_keys, but I'm encountering the same issues. The errors that are occurring are as follows: ValueError: Did not find redis_url, please add an environment variable 'REDIS_URL' which contains it, or pass 'redis_url' as a named parameter, or ConnectionError: Connection closed by server. redis vectorstore. The errors vary depending on different parameters of the Redis.from_texts function. The script worked perfectly when we connected it to local Redis and Pinecone databases. My code is provided below:

```
#db:redis/docker, source:pdf, webapp:streamlit

 

import os

import redis

import streamlit as st

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter

from langchain.vectorstores.redis import Redis

from langchain.llms import OpenAI

from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone

from urllib.parse import quote_plus

import pinecone

import spacy

import redis

from apikey import apikey




os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = apikey

 


# Postavke za povezivanje na Azure Redis

redis_host = '#######'

redis_port = '#######'

redis_password = '#######'



encoding='utf-8'

decode_responses=True

 



redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(

    host=redis_host,

    port=redis_port,

    password=redis_password,

    ssl=True,

    ssl_cert_reqs=None,  # Za neobavezne SSL certifikate

    ssl_ca_certs=None  # Putanja do CA certifikata ako je potrebno

)

 


try:

              
 # Testiranje pinga na Redis server

    result = redis_client.ping()

    if result:

        st.write("Veza s Redis serverom je uspešno uspostavljena!")

    else:

        st.write("Neuspešno testiranje veze s Redis serverom.")

 

except Exception as e:

    st.write("Došlo je do greške pri povezivanju s Redis serverom:", e)

 



with st.sidebar:

 

    st.title(' Chat with your Data')

 

   

 

def split_text_into_chunks(text, max_chunk_size):

    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

    # Tokenizacija teksta na rečenice

    doc = nlp(text)

    #doc=text

    sentences = [sent.text for sent in doc.sents]

 

    chunks = []

    current_chunk = ""

    for sentence in sentences:

        if len(current_chunk) + len(sentence) <= max_chunk_size:

            current_chunk += sentence

        else:

            chunks.append(current_chunk.strip())

            current_chunk = sentence

    chunks.append(current_chunk.strip())

   

    return chunks

 

 

 

def main():

 

    st.header("Chat with your own PDF")

    pdf = 'Serbia.pdf'

    

    if pdf is not None:

 

        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)

 

        texts = []

 

        for page in pdf_reader.pages:

 

            text = page.extract_text()

 

            page_chunks = split_text_into_chunks(text,50)

 

            texts.extend(page_chunks)

 

            st.write(texts)


 

        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

 

        VectorStore = Redis.from_texts(texts, embeddings, redis_conn=redis_client)

        VectorStore.url = None

 

      

 

        query = st.text_input("Ask questions related to your PDF")

 

        st.write(embeddings)

 


        if query:

            results = VectorStore.similarity_search(query=query, k=3)

            llm = OpenAI()

            chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff")

            response = chain.run(input_documents=results, question=query)

            st.write(response)

 

 

if __name__ == '__main__':

 

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using Langchain. They expect the url not the client. it works perfectly locally because the default is the default localhost address of redis. The initialized connection you're passing in does nothing.

Try the following:

```py
import redis

def format_redis_conn_from_env(using_ssl=False):
    start = "rediss://" if using_ssl else "redis://"
    # if using RBAC
    password = os.getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD", None)
    username = os.getenv("REDIS_USERNAME", "default")
    if password is not None:
        start += f"{username}:{password}@"

    return start + f"{os.getenv('REDIS_ADDRESS')}:{os.getenv('REDIS_PORT')}"


# make using_ssl=True to use SSL with ACRE (Azure redis enterprise)
redis_address = format_redis_conn_from_env(using_ssl=False)


# pass url to langchain
from langchain.vectorstores import Redis
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
redisearch = RediSearch.from_texts(
   texts,
   embeddings,
   redis_url=redis_address
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to implement your solution, but I'm facing an issue with importing RediSearch. I tried using "pip install RediSearch" and then importing it. I've also noticed that there's an option to deploy RediSearch on Azure. What do you suggest as the best option, considering I haven't had the chance to work with it before?

Comment: You need two things to get started. A redis client, in this case ``redis-py``, and a Redis database with the search and query capability enabled.

The first is quick: ``pip install redis`` 

The second you have options:
1. Redis cloud
2. redis stack docker container (``docker run -d -p 6379:6379 -p 8001:8001 redis/redis-stack:latest``)
3. Azure, AWS, or GCP marketplace's Redis Enterprise offering.

There are others, but I highly recommend the redis cloud approach. If you are familiar with docker and can use that, thats very simple for local dev too.